Setting JWT Cookies from Express Backend to Frontend
i am trying to set the cookie using JWT. On localhost everything works like charm. But when i deploy my FE(front-end) and BE(back-end) on render.com. i can login but after that i get the errors Unauthorized.
i am using reactJs for FE and expressJs for BE.
Here is my express server :
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import setupSocket from "./lib/socket.js";
import http from "http";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

// Routes import here
import postRoute from "./routes/post.route.js";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js";
import testRoute from "./routes/test.route.js";
import userRoute from "./routes/user.route.js";
import chatRoute from "./routes/chat.route.js";
import messageRoute from "./routes/message.route.js";

const app = express();
app.set("trust proxy", 1);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const cookieParserSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY; // Secret key for signing cookies
app.use(cookieParser(cookieParserSecret));

app.use(
cors({
origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL 
methods: \["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"\], // Uncomment to restrict HTTP methods
credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies)
})
);

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/test", testRoute);
app.use("/api/chats", chatRoute);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoute);

const server = http.createServer(app); // Create HTTP server using Express app
const io = setupSocket(server); // Setup socket.io

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8800;
server.listen(PORT, () =\> {
console.log(Server is running on port ${PORT});
});

//-------- express server ends here -------------
here is my code for setting the Cookie in the BE:
res
.cookie("token", token, {
withCredentials: true,
httpOnly: true,
sameSite: "none",
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // Set secure only in production
maxAge: age,
path: "/",
domain: process.env.CLIENT_URL || "localhost:5173",
})
.status(200)
.json(userInfo);

//-------- Cookie code ends here -------------
Here is my FE axios code :

import axios from "axios";

const apiRequest = axios.create({
baseURL: process.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL,
withCredentials: true,
});

export default apiRequest;


//-------- axios baseURL ends here -------------
here is how i making request


try {
const response = await apiRequest.post("/auth/login", {
username,
password,
});

updateUser(response.data);
navigate("/");

} catch (err) {
console.log(err.response.data.message);
setError(err.response.data.message);
} finally {
setLoading(false);
}


//-------- FE making post request ends here -------------
here is how i am trying to verify my token:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) =\> {
const token = req.cookies.token;
console.log("Token on backend: ", token);

if (!token) {
return res.status(401).json({
message: "You are not authorized!",
});
}
try {
const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);

req.userId = decoded.id; // Extract user ID from decoded token

next(); // Proceed to the next middleware
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);

return res.status(403).json({
message: "Token is not valid!",
});
}
};


//-------- verify token ends here -------------
Here is my domain name for the frontend:
fr-real-estate-1.onrender.com

And here is my domain name for the backend:
fr-real-estate.onrender.com

The problem is, when I change,
sameSite: "lax" to sameSite: "none",
my cookie is not being set after login. However, when I set sameSite: "lax", my cookie is being set, but it gets destroyed or is missing when I reload the page.
Can someone please tell me what I should do in this case?
More i can login is this mean its not cors issue ?
but after login i get these below errors :
GET fr-real-estate.onrender.com/api/us... 401 (Unauthorized)

Error fetching notifications:
 {message: 'Request failed with status code 401', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 401"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: {…}, status: 401, statusText: '', headers: Ds, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n at p1 (fr-real-estate-1.onrender.com/asse... at XMLHttpRequest._ (fr-real-estate-1.onrender.com/asse... at is.request (fr-real-estate-1.onrender.com/asse... at async fetch (fr-real-estate-1.onrender.com/asse... Error


i struggled alot and already tried many ways and spend many days on it. but nothing fixed my problem.
Please help me.
i will really be thankful for any lead or help.
i tried changing cookies setting and giving cors direct my FE url. But this didn't fix my problem.

localhost:5173 is not a valid Web origin; try http://localhost:5173 in your CORS configuration instead.

Hi @jub0bs, i already tried this and also tried with different ways like
origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
and
origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL || "http://localhost:5173",
But nothing fixed the problem.

That's one problem among several. Other issues I'm noticing in your code: 1) localhost:5173 is not a valid value for the Domain cookie attribute; browsers will reject attempts to set such a cookie. 2) SameSite: None requires Secure in several moderns browsers, but you're only setting the cookie as Secure in prod. 3) withCredentials doesn't correspond to any cookie attribute.

I urge you to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Hi @jub0bs, thank you for sharing the link above. Let me check if it fixes my problem.

Any update? Is it working now or not?
